# What does it mean for an equicontinuous family of continuous functions to be uniformly equicontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, equicontinuity

Here is the definition I am given to equicontinuity:

> [image]

I found this question here:

[Is an equicontinuous family of uniformly continuous functions necessarily uniformly equicontinuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2594543/is-an-equicontinuous-family-of-uniformly-continuous-functions-necessarily-unifor)

**but I do not understand the definition of an equicontinuous family of continuous functions  to be uniformly equicontinuous from it, could anyone tell me the definition of uniformly equicontinuous family of functions (in a way similar to the definition given above (without using small n)), please?**

Now, I want to show that: **an equicontinuous family of continuous functions on a compact metric space is uniformly equicontinuous.**

And I found this question and its solution online:

> [image]
>
> [image]

And I found not less than 3 questions here on this site that answers a question similar to mine but not exactly mine(I have read them all), so could anyone help me proof this question: **an equicontinuous family of continuous functions on a compact metric space is uniformly equicontinuous.** and tell me how I will use compactness of the given metric space in the proof?

Comment: Your 11.27 calls *equicontinuous* what the linked questions calls *uniformly equicontinuous*. The linked question calls equicontinuous a family of functions such that for all $x$ and $\varepsilon$ there is some $\delta$ such that, for all $f$ in the family and for all $y$ such that $d(x,y)<\delta$, $\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\varepsilon$.

Comment: ohh, but I have to answer the question based on my definition @Gae.S. so what is the definition of uniformly equicontinuous based on my definition?

Comment: Actually the exact definition for equicontinuity I was given is: A collection $\mathcal{F}$ of real-valued functions on a metric space $X$ is equicontinuous at $x \in X$ if $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0,$ such that  $\forall f \in \mathcal{F}, \forall x' \in X, $ we have $$\rho (x, x') < \delta \implies |f(x) - f(x')| < \epsilon $$  .... is this the same definition as the one given in 11.27 @Gae.S.?

Comment: If by *equicontinuous* you have been given "a family is equicontinuous if and only if it is equicontinuous at all points", then no, it isn't the same as 11.27. Personally, I'd call 11.27 *uniformly equicontinuous*.

Comment: yes the remainder of my definition(the definition I stated in my previous comment) is $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous on $X$ if it is equicontinuous at every point of $X.$@Gae.S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See lemma 1 in [my note here](http://at.yorku.ca/p/a/c/a/23.pdf), which establishes this. The weaker notion is more pointwise; in its metric formulation:

$$\forall x\forall \varepsilon \exists \delta>0: \forall f \in \mathcal{F}: \forall y: (d(x,y) < \delta) \to \rho(f(x),f(y)) < \delta$$

so that we can find, given $x$,and $\varepsilon$, a $\delta$ that works for all functions at $x$, while the notion you defined is uses the same $\delta$ for all pairs $x,y$ and all $f$ at the same time. It's a similar difference between continuity at $x$ and uniform continuity.

You'll need to know the [Lebesgue number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma) lemma for the proof, as a basic fact about compact metric spaces.

Comment: Did you read the definition actually I have in my comments ? .... is it different from 11.27?

Comment: @Emptymind it's the same as my definition: you have equicontinuous at all $x$, while mine has the $\forall x$ at the beginning, same thing. It's the pointwise vs uniform gap. Bridged by compactness. 11.27 is my EQ2, yours from the comments or mine in in the answer is EQ1.

Comment: Can not we interchange the usage of the Lebesgue number by an argument similar to the solution picture I attached above in the question?

Comment: @Emptymind You probably could, try to come up with one and post it as your own answer (this is the recommended way).

Comment: Okay and I will ask you to see if it is correct or no ... ok?

Comment: @Emptymind sure, that way you learn the most.

Comment: If you have time, could you look at this, please?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3573238/an-example-of-int-x-times-y-f-d-mu-times-lambda-is-finite-but-such-th